# Set multiple objects to a setTimeout function

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to setTimeout to multiple objects so their events occur in exactly same timespan?

This is what I have so far, but it is returning me a syntax error:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
$('#post_confirm').fadeOut('slow');}, 
$('#chat').height($chatHeight_user);}, 
1000);
```

Comment: looks like a syntax error to me, one too many `}` if i'm seeing it right.

Comment: Can you just lose the `},` on the second line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error, use:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#post_confirm').fadeOut('slow'); // lose the }, here
    $('#chat').height($chatHeight_user);
}, 1000);
```

`setTimeout()` works like this:

```
setTimeout(callback,time)
```

So you can replace `callback` with a single anonymous function that has all the other code in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  $('#post_confirm').fadeOut('slow'); 
  $('#chat').height($chatHeight_user); 
},1000);
```